# Show that the ideal $((x_1-\alpha_1)^{t_1},...,(x_n-\alpha_n)^{t_n})$ is primary.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, primary-decomposition

> Show that for all choices of $t_1,...,t_n \in \mathbb{N}$, the ideal
>   $$Q = ((x_1-\alpha_1)^{t_1},...,(x_n-\alpha_n)^{t_n})$$
>   of $R=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is primary.

What I've done: we have that $Q \subseteq M$, where $M = (x_1-\alpha_1,...,x_n-\alpha_n)$ is a maximal ideal. I'll show that $R/Q$ is non zero and every zero divisor of $R/Q$ is nilpotent.

Let $a = f + Q, b = g + Q \in R/Q$ such that $ab = 0 $ but $b \neq 0$ (i.e, $g \notin Q$). Since $fg \in Q \subseteq M$, and $M$ is maximal then prime, we have $f \in M$ or $g \in M$. I was able to show that if $f \in M$ then there is a power $k$ of  $f$ such that $f^k \in Q$, that is, $a$ is nilpotent.

My quest is: How can I show, from $g \notin Q$, that $g \notin M$?

(This is the exercise 4.38 from Sharp)

Comment: What about the alternative solution: $\sqrt Q=M$ and $M$ is a maximal ideal?

Comment: I thought about that. But for this I would have to show that $(x_i - \alpha_i)$ is a prime ideal, for all $i$ , but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Not sure why need this, but $x_i-a_i$ are irreducible polynomials, so they generate prime ideals.

Comment: I was thinking about using $rad(I+J) = rad(rad(I)+rad(J))$ and $rad(P^k) = P$ if $P$ is prime ideal. But I just saw quasi's answer, we only need $M^k \subseteq Q \subseteq M$.

Comment: Btw, by using the automorphism $x_i\mapsto x_i-\alpha_i$ (for $i=1,\dots,n$) of $R$ we can reduce the question to show that the ideal $(x_1^{t_1},...,x_n^{t_n})$ is primary.

Comment: I don't see why this automorphism reduce the question to show that the ideal $(x_{1}^{t_1},...,x_{n}^{t_n}).$ By using the properties I mentioned above, $(x_{1}^{t_1},...,x_{n}^{t_n})$ is primary.

Comment: Which ideal corresponds to Q is the above mentioned automorphism?

Comment: You saying that $Q$ corresponds to $(x_{1}^{t_1},...,x_{n}^{t_n})$. And Inverse image of primary is primary, so $Q$ is primary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a,b\in R$, and suppose $ab\in Q$.

We want to show $a\in Q$ or $b^m\in Q$, for some positive integer $m$.

Let $k=\max\{t_1,...,t_n\}$.

Then $M^{nk} \subseteq Q \subseteq M$.

In particular, if $b\in M$, then $b^{nk}\in Q$, and we're done.

Suppose $b\not\in M$.

It remains to show $a\in Q$.

From $M^{nk} \subseteq Q \subseteq M$, we get $\text{rad}(Q)=M$.

Hence $M$ is the only prime ideal containing $Q$.

Since $b\not\in M$, it follows that the ideal $(Q,b)$ is not contained in any maximal ideal, hence 
\begin{align*}
&(Q,b)=(1)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a(Q,b) = (a)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a\in a(Q,b)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a\in a(Q+(b))\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a\in aQ+(ab)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a\in Q\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have two questions:
1) why $b \notin M$ imples $(Q, b)$ is not contained in any maximal ideal?
2) Following my attempt, there is no way we can garantee $g \notin M?$ since $g \notin Q$?.

Comment: @P.G: Since $\text{rad}(Q)=M$, any prime ideal containing $Q$ must contain $M$, hence, since $M$ is maximal, $M$ is the _only_ prime ideal containing $Q$. If $(I,b)$ was contained in some maximal ideal, $N$ say, then since $N$ contains $I$, we must have $N=M$, contrary to the assumption that $b\not\in M$.

Answer (score 3):

To show that the ideal is primary, you need to show that $f\in M$ using that $g \not \in Q$. You cannot prove that $g \not\in M$ as you can see with some simple examples (take $Q=(x^2)$ in $K[x]$ and $f=g=x$).

So in the case that $g\in M$, assume for the sake of contradiction that $f\not \in M$. Let $h$ s.t. $fh-1\in M$ (inverse modulo $M$). We know that $fh-1$ is nilpotent modulo $Q$ so $(fh-1)^k\in Q$, which proves that there exists $h'$ s.t. $fh'-1\in Q$. So we have $fg \in Q$, and $fgh'-g\in Q$ so $g\in Q$, which is a contradiction.